# Unable to Connect to Sequel Pro

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelpro

When I have tried to access Sequel Pro I keep getting the following error message:

> "Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 because access was denied.
>
> Double-check your username and password and ensure that access from
>   your current location is permitted.
>
> MySQL said: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

I have downloaded MySQL but that for some reason will not show up in the terminal, have I not downloaded that properly or is there some other issue?

I have tried using different passwords and usernames and downloaded mysql again, if there is an easier way to access SQL I am all ears and would appreciate a simple explanation to gain access to SQL.

> "Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 because access was denied.
>
> Double-check your username and password and ensure that access from
>   your current location is permitted.
>
> MySQL said: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password:
>   NO)"

Comment: did you set a root password when you installed mysql? If so, that's the password you should be using to connect.

Comment: _"I have tried using different passwords"_  the error message **using password: NO** indicates that you are trying to connect without a password